# Which framework is suitable for selenium project

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using the selenium for automation. In our project we are importing a data from excel file, then compile that data with web tool and compare the tool output with expected value, which is in excel file. For this project which frame work is suitable? And please explain how that frame work is design. Also if possible please share any link or example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you will be comparing two output files (Excel files), this has nothing to do with selenium, use [EPPLUS][1] with C#


  [1]: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Not comparing two excel files. I have importing a data from excel file and output which is coming from tool is comparing with expected data. And also UI Functionality is there. So we are using selenium.For this project I want choose a framework. but not able to understand which frame work shall use.

Comment: you are saying that you use selenium, then what is your question? the framework is selenium

Comment: I want to use a framework for this project. please suggest which framework will use.

Answer (score 0):

Use page object model. It is highly flexible and maintainable. Most of the industries is using page object model for their automation stuff

Few reference to know about page object model:-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

Few reference for Page object model in C#:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1013318/Page-Object-Design-Pattern

http://automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/

Hope it will help you :)